# VSTS REST API permission for POST requests

Tags: azure-devops

I need to adjust the VSTS permissions for API level POST requests. So that users should not be able to get any response or result by a POST request. But still GET requests should be worked. So how can I adjust the authorization level only for REST API POST requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give users who just have permissions to request GET REST API (not POST), you just need **provider PAT with read permissions for related scopes**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Marina :) But I am using "Alternate authentication credentials" instead of  PAT. So is there a way to select the scope in that case as well?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can not select scopes for Alternate authentication credentials. It's only available for PAT.